# MonoTouch - Extract Image from Sqlite Database Blob

Tags: sqlite, xamarin.ios, blob

I am trying to get a GIF/PNG/JPG image out of a Sqlite database. Is there a way in Monotouch to convert the Blob field to an image?

I'm guessing:

Get data byte[] from SQLite into a memory stream:

```
MemoryStream blob = new MemoryStream(blobFromSQLite[]);
```

Load the data into a NSData object via the stream:

```
UIImage.LoadFromData(NSData.FromStream(blob));
```

But how do I get a stream from a sqlite field?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest way to do it is this:

```
byte[] myBuffer = null;
using (SqliteCommand sqlCom = new SqliteCommand(sqlCon)) //assuming sqlCon is your SqliteConnection
{

    sqlCom.CommandText = "SELECT Images FROM MyTable WHERE Name = 'MyImage.png'";

    using (SqliteDataReader dbReader = sqlCom.ExecuteReader())
    {

        if (dbReader.HasRows)
        {

            while (dbReader.Read())
            {

                myBuffer = (byte[])dbReader["Images"];

            }

         }

    }
}
```

To get it as a `UIImage`, you don't have to use a stream at all:

```
UIImage.LoadFromData(NSData.FromArray(myBuffer));
```